# GLSurfacView.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated() implementation not recognized by compiler

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to implement GLSurfaceView.Renderer into a class and it seems to not recognize that I am implementing its functions:

```
package com.example.Test3d;

import android.opengl.EGLConfig;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import com.example.Test3d.Shader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


public class Rendering implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{

  private FloatBuffer vertbuffer;

  public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
  {
    Shader.makeprogram();
    
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Shader.positionhandle);
    float[] verts=
    {
      0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
      0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
      1.0f,1.0f,0.0f
    };
    
    vertbuffer = makefloatbuffer(verts);
  }

//And some other code

}
```

Java N-IDE tells me that there is no implementation of GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onCreateSurface(GL10,EGLConfig)

The weird thing is that there's tow other functions to be implemented and I don't get errors out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/18553920. It was the wrong import. It was `import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;` instead of `import android.opengl.EGLConfig;`